# Elliptic Curve has no $p$-torsion over $K_n$

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm currently studying [Gross' paper](https://www.wstein.org/papers/bib/gross-kolyvagins_work_on_modular_elliptic_curves.pdf) about modular elliptic curves. Lemma 4.3 is quite difficult for me to understand. It states that an elliptic $E$ has no $p$-torsion rational over $K_n$, the ring class field of order $n$. The only thing I seem to know by now is that there is a well defined representation $\rho:\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(E_p)/\mathbb{Q})\to \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$.

Any insights on this, or references recommended? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There’s a proof given. What part of it are you stuck at/unclear about? It would also be more polite to define the terms you are using rather than make people go to a link.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192771/galois-representations-and-isogenies-of-elliptic-curves) help at all? The point is that $\rho$ contains the trivial representation if and only if $E$ has $p$-torsion. Or is your confusion at another part of the proof?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Gross splits the problem in two cases (due to Mazur), $E_p(K_n)=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and $E_p(K_n)=(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^2$. Supposing $E$ has $p$-torsion, I understand that $\rho$ contains the trivial representation. I struggle with the assertions that follow and why they contradict the hypothesis.